# Plot performance during training from lightGBM in TidyModels (tuning number of trees)

Tags: r, lightgbm, tidymodels

I am trying to plot model performance of lightGBM models for training and validation sets using TidyModels.  I'd like to be able to extract metric (e.g. RMSE) performance on training & validation sets for every nth tree during training.

So for example I would like to plot RMSE for the 10th, 20th, 30th...500th trees for both training and validation sets, plot the curves, and then see where training performance flattens and/or validation deteriorates.

Apologies for no reprex with this, but the task is a generic one.

I have been using lightGBM (with the bonsai package) for my modelling & I've searched here and the Tidymodels sites, but can't find anything specific on this.  I'm assuming that this data is saved in an object somewhere, but I've not found it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're indeed correct that that data is saved inside the object. :)

The metrics you choose to evaluate with, as well as their values, are stored inside of the underlying lightgbm object that the tidymodels object wraps. After training with tidymodels, we can subset out the underlying engine fit with `extract_fit_engine()`, and then use lightgbm's interface to work with that object as usual. (An aside, though: be sure to use the tidymodels objects for prediction.)

In this reprex, I use bonsai's shorthand `validation` argument to allot 20% of the supplied training data for validation, which is what those resulting metrics are computed on. If you'd like to evaluate with non-default metrics, you can pass those to `set_engine()` as well with lightgbm's usual argument structure.

```r
library(lightgbm)
#> Loading required package: R6
library(tidymodels)
library(bonsai)

# fit the model using tidymodels---note that we use the `validation`
# argument to interface with lightgbm validation sets
pars_fit <-
  boost_tree() %>%
  set_engine("lightgbm", validation = .2) %>%
  set_mode("regression") %>%
  fit(bill_length_mm ~ ., data = penguins)

pars_fit
#> parsnip model object
#> 
#> <lgb.Booster>
#>   Public:
#>     add_valid: function (data, name) 
#>     best_iter: 52
#>     best_score: 6.97993052849227
#>     current_iter: function () 
#>     dump_model: function (num_iteration = NULL, feature_importance_type = 0L) 
#>     eval: function (data, name, feval = NULL) 
#>     eval_train: function (feval = NULL) 
#>     eval_valid: function (feval = NULL) 
#>     finalize: function () 
#>     initialize: function (params = list(), train_set = NULL, modelfile = NULL, 
#>     lower_bound: function () 
#>     params: list
#>     predict: function (data, start_iteration = NULL, num_iteration = NULL, 
#>     raw: NA
#>     record_evals: list
#>     reset_parameter: function (params, ...) 
#>     rollback_one_iter: function () 
#>     save: function () 
#>     save_model: function (filename, num_iteration = NULL, feature_importance_type = 0L) 
#>     save_model_to_string: function (num_iteration = NULL, feature_importance_type = 0L) 
#>     set_train_data_name: function (name) 
#>     to_predictor: function () 
#>     update: function (train_set = NULL, fobj = NULL) 
#>     upper_bound: function () 
#>   Private:
#>     eval_names: l2
#>     get_eval_info: function () 
#>     handle: lgb.Booster.handle
#>     higher_better_inner_eval: FALSE
#>     init_predictor: NULL
#>     inner_eval: function (data_name, data_idx, feval = NULL) 
#>     inner_predict: function (idx) 
#>     is_predicted_cur_iter: list
#>     name_train_set: training
#>     name_valid_sets: list
#>     num_class: 1
#>     num_dataset: 2
#>     predict_buffer: list
#>     set_objective_to_none: FALSE
#>     train_set: lgb.Dataset, R6
#>     train_set_version: 1
#>     valid_sets: list
```

Subsetting out the underlying engine fit:

```r
# extract the underlying fit
lgb_fit <- extract_fit_engine(pars_fit)

lgb_fit
#> <lgb.Booster>
#>   Public:
#>     add_valid: function (data, name) 
#>     best_iter: 52
#>     best_score: 6.97993052849227
#>     current_iter: function () 
#>     dump_model: function (num_iteration = NULL, feature_importance_type = 0L) 
#>     eval: function (data, name, feval = NULL) 
#>     eval_train: function (feval = NULL) 
#>     eval_valid: function (feval = NULL) 
#>     finalize: function () 
#>     initialize: function (params = list(), train_set = NULL, modelfile = NULL, 
#>     lower_bound: function () 
#>     params: list
#>     predict: function (data, start_iteration = NULL, num_iteration = NULL, 
#>     raw: NA
#>     record_evals: list
#>     reset_parameter: function (params, ...) 
#>     rollback_one_iter: function () 
#>     save: function () 
#>     save_model: function (filename, num_iteration = NULL, feature_importance_type = 0L) 
#>     save_model_to_string: function (num_iteration = NULL, feature_importance_type = 0L) 
#>     set_train_data_name: function (name) 
#>     to_predictor: function () 
#>     update: function (train_set = NULL, fobj = NULL) 
#>     upper_bound: function () 
#>   Private:
#>     eval_names: l2
#>     get_eval_info: function () 
#>     handle: lgb.Booster.handle
#>     higher_better_inner_eval: FALSE
#>     init_predictor: NULL
#>     inner_eval: function (data_name, data_idx, feval = NULL) 
#>     inner_predict: function (idx) 
#>     is_predicted_cur_iter: list
#>     name_train_set: training
#>     name_valid_sets: list
#>     num_class: 1
#>     num_dataset: 2
#>     predict_buffer: list
#>     set_objective_to_none: FALSE
#>     train_set: lgb.Dataset, R6
#>     train_set_version: 1
#>     valid_sets: list
```

Some of the slots in the underlying fit have their names set by tidymodels, so you may need to poke around a bit to figure out how we've passed different lightgbm arguments.

It's my understanding that the [`plot_metrics` functionality from the Python API](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.plot_metric.html) is [not yet ported over to R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lightgbm/lightgbm.pdf). We can put together our own plot with their other methods and some quick dplyr and ggplot, though:

```r
# use lightgbm's interface to retrieve l2 for each iteration
eval_results <- lgb.get.eval.result(lgb_fit, data_name = "validation", eval_name = "l2")

# drop into data frame
tibble(l2 = eval_results, iteration = seq_along(eval_results)) %>%
  # subset out every 10th iteration, starting at 1
  slice(seq(from = 1, to = length(eval_results), by = 10)) %>%
  # plot
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = iteration, y = l2) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That looks to be what I was looking for. Thank you!  As you say I will have to do some poking around to see how TidyModels bring through the lightGBM terms - especially as I was using cross-validation rather than single training & validate sets.  Any advice on this would be gratefully received.